# "Vous êtes" or "Êtes-vous" ?

Tags: grammaire, ordre-des-mots, questions

A friend of mine and I was discussing around the difference between “Vous êtes” and “Êtes-vous” – and I couldn't conclude nothing.

So, are “Vous êtes” and “Êtes-vous” the same thing? If not, what is the difference? Is “Êtes-vous” for questions? And, can I say the following?

> Vous êtes beau/belle.
>
> Êtes-vous beau/belle.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In formal language, affirmations have *subject – verb – object complements* order and yes/no questions have *verb – subject – object complements* order. So,

- *Vous êtes beau* is an affirmation.
- *Êtes-vous beau ?* is a yes/no question.

  (If the subject is not already a pronoun, it comes first and a pronoun is added after the verb to form questions. E.g. *Pierre est-il beau ?*)

In casual language you'll find two more ways to ask a question:

- *Est-ce que vous êtes beau ?*

  Here, the subject–verb inversion is limited (internal) to the universal “*Est-ce que*” question introducer.
- *Vous êtes beau ?* …with the appropriate intonation.

  In this case only the intonation (or the question mark in writing) allows one to understand it's a question.

Answer (score 4):

The second form is missing a question mark so should be:

> Êtes-vous beau/belle ?

i.e.

> Are you handsome?

and cannot be but a question, the first one is just a statement (or a lazy/casual style question).

> You are handsome[?]